# PHP and basic RESTful services; GET requesting all records vs one record

Tags: php, rest, get

My PHP class has a project involving RESTful services where we have a basic service set up like this:

```
$request = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
switch($request) {
    case 'GET':
        $user = $acctReader->read($_GET["username"], $_GET["password"]);
        if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $user == true) {
            // echo method to return single record from db after validating that $user is an account in a separate table
        } elseif (!isset($_GET["id"] && $user == true) {
            // echo method to return ALL records from db
        }
    case 'POST':
    case 'PUT':
    case 'DELETE':
    default
}
```

I'm in the midst of having the GET to respond to user validation in such that if they enter in a valid username/password but *do not* explicitly request a single id, they should see all the records 
Here's what part of my html looks like:

```
<form action="TaskService.php" method="GET">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required/><br />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/><br />
        <label for="id">Task ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="optional"/>
        <input type="submit" name="getTask" value="GET TASK"/>
</form>
```

I was able to verify that my first conditional (where the username, pw, and an id are entered) that it returns one value.  However, I am having trouble with having it give me *all* records when I don't pass an id in. 
 Any ideas on where I should be making my changes?

Comment: Where is the method you use to return all records?

Comment: I don't know your exact usage here but it looks like you're returning all users if certain data isn't sent in the request.  I'm not sure that's a good idea because 1) if your user database grows sufficiently large then you're going to be moving a huge amount of data, and 2) you're basically making your entire user database public.  If the browser can see all users then so can anybody else.

Comment: @GordonM, yup that makes perfect sense.  In the case of my question above, this is only in relation to my class.  We have only been learning _very_ basic concepts of REST and simply how it can work.  This is definitely not an elegant solution in a real-world sense, but it's predominate purpose is to be a starting off point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_GET["id"]` will be SET even if it is empty. You will have to either us

```
if (!empty($_GET["id"]) && $user == true) {
    // echo method to return single record from db after validating that $user is an account in a separate table
} else {
    // echo method to return ALL records from db
}
```

Or

```
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] != '' && $user == true) {
    // echo method to return single record from db after validating that $user is an account in a separate table
} else {
    // echo method to return ALL records from db
}
```

> But beware of using `empty()` when the field could contains
>
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
>
> as these are all considered as empty
>
> [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, totally spaced using `empty()`