# PHP RESTful services; AJAX and DELETE method with username/password credentials

Tags: php, ajax, rest

I asked another question related to RESTful services [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36782096/4190664), and have another question involving DELETE (PUT): 
Same kind of situation where I want to send along user credentials (username/password) with my PUT.  This is my DELETE service so far:

```
$http_req   = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
switch ($http_req) {
    case DELETE:
        $user = $acct->read($_REQUEST["usernameDel"], $_REQUEST["passwordDel"]);  // this method used to read db table with 1 record
        if (!empty($_REQUEST["delTaskId"]) && isset($_REQUEST["usernameDel"]) && isset($_REQUEST["passwordDel"])) {
            if ($user == true) {
                $delete     = fopen("php://input", "r");
                $data       = stream_get_contents($deleted);
                $params;
                parse_str($data, $params);
                $dropped = $mgr->delete($params["id"])  // calls the method that deletes a particular row based on its id
                echo $dropped;
            }
        }                
}
```

This is the html page I am working with. I updated it to be in a :

```
<form action="TaskService.php" method="POST">
<label for="usernameDel">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="usernameDel" id="usernameDel" required/><br />
<label for="passwordDel">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordDel" id="passwordDel" required/><br />
<label for="delTaskId">Task ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="delTaskId" id="delTaskId" required/><br /><br />
<button type="button" id="btnDelete">Delete Task</button><br /><br />
</form>
```

This is my ajax code (edit-now using @Devs modifications):

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
            method: "DELETE",  
            url: "TaskService.php",  
            data: { 'username':$("#usernameDel").val(), 'password': $("#passwordDel").val(), 'id': $("#delTaskId").val()},
            success: function(theResponse) {
                alert(theResponse);
            }
        });
});
```

Currently it returns a 200 response, but gives me the error messages I had put in for my Account class (comes back with "Could not find account". 
My gut is telling me it has something to do with my `$_REQUEST[]` superglobals since it's not doing anything with a form action, but I am not all too familiar with passing information via ajax 
Thoughts?

Comment: In the above question, Is the first block of php codes inside TaskService.php?

Comment: @Devs yes, it's all part of that TaskService.php file

Answer (score 0):

Just arranged the ajax format, also some syntax error in the php code.

**Note:** never tested

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   $("#btnDelete").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
                method: "DELETE",  
                url: "TaskService.php",  
                data: { 'username':$("#usernameDel").val(), 'password': $("#passwordDel").val(), 'id': $("#delTaskId").val()},
                success: function(theResponse) {

                    // Output 
                    alert(theResponse); // comment this

                    }  
            });
    });
});
```

**TaskService.php**

```
<?php
$http_req   = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

switch ($http_req) {
    case DELETE:
        $user = $acct->read($_REQUEST["username"], $_REQUEST["password"]);  // this method used to read db table with 1 record
        if ($user == true) {
            $delete     = fopen("php://input", "r");
            $data       = stream_get_contents($deleted);
            $params;
            parse_str($data, $params);
            $dropped = $mgr->delete($params["id"]);  // calls the method that deletes a particular row based on its id
            echo $dropped;
        }
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Not to sound finicky, but is there a way to refactor it to use ´"method":"delete"´ instead of doing a ´POST´?

Comment: I gave this a shot and it is still returning the same error response I created "Could not find account".  So it seems like it isn't properly validating the username/pw. Note: my html snippet _is not_ within a form...it is simply labels and input elements. Would this have anything to do with it not finding the correct information?

Answer (score 0):

Found out why my validation wasn't working! I feel so blind! 
I was ignoring the fact that the delete action was taking username, password, and id as parameters....as such, validation wasn't going to work because the "php://input" file hadn't been opened to parse through *all 3* parameters. 
Here's my updated PHP that works:

```
// I needed to access the file FIRST before doing anything with the parameters passed from AJAX
$deleted    = fopen("php://input", "r");
$data       = stream_get_contents($deleted);
$params;
parse_str($data, $params);

$user_auth  = $acctMgr->readAcct($params["username"], $params["password"]);
        if ($user_auth == true) {
            $rows   = $mgr->delete($params["id"]);

            echo $rows;
        } else {
            echo "User not authenticated";
        }
```